# Projects using compatible Sentinel-2 and Landsat-8 reflectance data

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, sentinel-2, nasa, esa

Right from the beginning on the Senintel-2 Satellites were constructed to harmonize with the Landsat-8 products in terms of their spatial and spectral capabilities. What I wonder is, if there are projects which really used this advantage. I know there is the NASA HLS Product. But I don't know of many projects that used the data produced by this campaign. 
If anyone knows of more projects, I'd be curious to hear about them

Answer (score 1):

I would check out the citing articles (n=108) from the 2018 NASA HLS paper:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0034425718304139?via%3Dihub

That should give you an idea of some of the projects that are using the data from the HLS campaign.